# how to change back color of rows in Grid control

Tags: gridcontrol, devexpress-windows-ui

I am Using Devexpress Grid Control . i Just want to know how to change the back colour of some particular rows on load the data in grid .
e.g
like in this table Only Male User rows become Green and Female rows Yellows

```
User             Class      Gender 
User1             7          Male
User2             7          Female
User3             7          Male
```

I want to know how this will be Accomplish?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CustomDrawCell` event (I believe) and check for the gender in the focused row, specific column.  You can then set the back color (I believe the parameter e will contain the `Appearance.BackColor`) to the desired color.